# How to execute a sudo command with php code?

Tags: php, linux, putty, ejabberd

I am executing a SUDO command in PHP script,

```
$username = 'tester';
$password = 'testerspassword';
$node = 'localhost';
exec('sudo /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);
```

When i am trying with putty and executing same as

```
sudo ejabberdctl register testuser1 localhost pass123
```

Its working , but through PHP script its not working.
How to execute it through PHP script,If required to include .ppk file and username for verification then how to use it ?

Comment: Note `php` executes its scripts through his uses (apache, I guess). Hence, you have to grant privileges to that user to execute the command.

Comment: Can you assist how to grant permissions ?

Comment: You have to add the permissions in sudoers, using `visudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is executed under the user account of Apache.

You should add this user(usually called www-data, apache or similar) to `/etc/sudoer`...

Comment: When doing that, remember restrict the permissions of apache (or whatever is called in your system) user to execute only that command. Otherwise, you would be facing security issues.